# How to display song lyric line by line while playing a song in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, avplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you display song lyrics in Karaoke style on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829648/how-do-you-display-song-lyrics-in-karaoke-style-on-the-iphone)

I am making a iPhone app and there is a feature to display song lyric while playing a song. It came up with 2 questions.

1. What's the industry standard format of song lyric which can be used for this? I heard there is a xml format with song lyric content and timeline information, does anyone know this?
2. Assuming I got this xml file or other format of song lyric, how can I use it while playing a song?

Comment: See the QA here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829648/how-do-you-display-song-lyrics-in-karaoke-style-on-the-iphone/11322208#11322208

Comment: Are you looking to get the song lyric data on the fly for ANY song, or are these going to be predefined songs and lyrics that you can control?

Comment: Basically, you have to have a timeline, specific to the particular recording you're playing (not just the song title), that identifies when each new line should be displayed.  Then you need to design your player so that you can identify the time relative to the song start and trigger the lyric display at appropriate times.  Several ways to do all of this, but the basic concepts would be the same.